# Phpunit: Class "PHPUnit\TextUI\Command" not found

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, autoload

I'm using phpunit for test.

I've put the autoload, psr-4 in cofiguration.json

```json
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4":{
            "Src\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

After that, I executed this command in cmd `composer dump-autoload`, and the test doesn't work. The outputs are that:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\phpUnitPractice>.\vendor\bin\phpunit tests\EasyTest.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "PHPUnit\TextUI\Command" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpUnitPractice\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:61
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpUnitPractice\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit on line 61

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PHPUnit\TextUI\Command" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpUnitPractice\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:61
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpUnitPractice\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit on line 61
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information goes inside `composer.json` not `configuration.json`, have a look at this [`composer.json`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8d08717f15d1bddf3d28124b928ccc3a5cfdf84b/composer.json#L7-L34) example. Then run `composer dump-autoload`.

So, you should have a file like this:

```json
{
    "require": {
        YOUR REQUIRES
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4":{
            "Src\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
}
```